# I again have a problem with protobuf.net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I backuped a project and then reinstalled my OS (Win 7, if it matters).
I reinstalled VS 2010, and I reinstalled the support of protobuf.net to VS 2010.

Before that, the serializing and de-serializing were both perfectly OKAY, but now the wont work, and every time i step into them with the debugger:
[image: Picture of the situation]

Comment: What does the exception *say*?

Comment: (I've updated my answer re the comments; in particular, see the point about pdb)

Comment: (some thoughts on what is actually *happening* added, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edit)

From the comments, it sounds like the question relates to the production versions from the [home page, here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). In which case, it simply sounds like the _fixed is the directory I did the build from.

You could try including the pdb (from the zip) alongside the dll; that is the debugging symbols, and will probably help the trace tool you are using. But more important is: what does the exception **say**?

---

Some psychic debugging... is it simply that it sits there doing nothing? That is the expected behaviour if the input stream is not yielding data, and hasn't formally closed itself - for example reading from an open socket that isn't sending data. Where are you reading from in this scenario?

Comment: @Marc - Perhaps he could have checked it out to that direct himself seeing as `protobuf-net_fixed` is the root directory name of the checkout.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - I know that "_fixed" is something I *have* used... it sounds like *at some point* I had a file from the wrong folder.

Comment: I really starting to get lost in the jungle of links =3. The only thing I know is that I downloaded this two: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/downloads/detail?name=protobuf-net-VS10.msi&can=2&q= and http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/downloads/detail?name=protobuf-net%20r282.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: (protobuf-net-VS10.msi & protobuf-net r282.zip )

Comment: @Gilad - then it makes perfect sense that source is not available... a better question, though, is: what does the exception *say*?

Comment: @Marc - No exception, the program just refuses to load and save the objects and don't tell me why. So I debugged and when i stepped into the piece of code that deserialized I got that image.

Comment: Definition: Refuse - Don't load data from the file and don't inform me on any problem

Comment: What do you mean by where do I reading from? Do you want the code? Or the type of file that I saved to?

Comment: @Gilad - some illustration of what you are doing would help, certainly. A reproducible scenario would be even better. If it isn't suitable for SO, please feel free to e-mail me directly if you want (see profile page)